# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable, wcf

I cannot get to the bottom of this error because it happens only in one instance, and I can't find any code that can be the cause of the error.

I have a 3.5 web service that I'm calling from a multi-threaded, CAB client. I have a bunch of unit tests against the web service (from both 3.5 and 2.0 code), and it works fine. However, in the actual application, it doesn't work 90% of the time and, the remaining 10% of the time, it decides to work.

The code:

```
Friend Function ExecuteSearch(ByVal query As String) As List(Of SomeObject)
    Dim searchResults As List(of Object) = _searcher.UserSearch(query)
    Return searchResults
End Function 

// In Searcher
Public Function UserSearch(ByVal query As String) As List(Of SomeObject)
    Return Translate(Search.GetResults(query))
End Function

// In Search
Public Function GetResults(ByVal query As String) As List(Of SomeObject)
    Dim service As New FinderService.FinderService()
    Dim results As New List(Of String)
    Dim serviceResults As IEnumerable(Of String) = service.Search(query)    // <-- ERRORS OUT HERE 

    results.AddRange(serviceResults)

    Return results
End Function

// In the service
Public Function Search(ByVal query As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Initialize() // Initializes the _accounts variable
        Dim results As New List(of String)
        For Each account As User In _accounts
            If a bunch of conditions Then
                results.Add(account.Name)
            End IF 
        End For 

        Return results 
End Function
```

The breakpoints hit these codes (in this order). The line that errors out is in the "GetResults" method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the service has been setup in singleton mode.

Comment: It's still unclear as to where the error is originating.  What line or library call throws the exception that you're getting?

Comment: I understand exception hits on the line in client, but in fact it is a propagation of an exception in the service.

Comment: @Greg D - the service is throwing the exception. I get a SOAPException with this error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, the Heisenbugs :D

Apparently _accounts get modified during the loop. You can alleviate it by doing

```
For Each account As User In _accounts.ToList()
```

so a copy of current _accounts is created and enumerated and not the actual collection that might change

Comment: _accounts is too large to be copied. Since I posted this question, I added a lock on the *only* location where _accounts gets updated, but that didn't make a difference.

public sub Initialize
    SyncLock _accounts
         _accounts.AddRange(get accounts from db)
    End SyncLock 
end sub

Comment: You realise you only copy references, not the whole contents So unless you have say half a billion accounts it won't be a problem? Nevertheless, if you want to add a lock, you have to to SyncLock ForEach loop either.

Comment: @wwosik -- not half a billion; just a couple of million. :-) I will go with the ToList.